# rest api return duplicate values in postman and spring boot h2

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am new spring boot developer and i am trying to develope and rest api . when I do it ,I get and issues that my api return two duplicated response in postman .But i  haven't code anythiong to get duplicated valuese in my code . the one of duplicate values is  my model clase variable and athor one is table's attribute name .

below response in postman

[image]

model class

```
public class person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
    private Long id;



    @Column(name = "name")
 
    private      String Name ;

    @Column(name ="surname")
 
    private   String Surname;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return Surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        Surname = surname;
    }

}
```

repository

```
@Repository
public interface personRepository extends JpaRepository<person,Long> {
}
```

controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/person")
public class personController {

    @Autowired
    private personRepository repository;

    public personController(personRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @GetMapping("/view/list/person")
    private List<person> viewperson() {
        return repository.findAll();
    }

    @PostMapping("/insert/person")
    private person savePerson(@RequestBody person obj) {

        return repository.save(obj);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/delete/{id}")
    private void delete(@PathVariable Long id) {

        repository.deleteById(id);
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialec
```

t

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're not following the proper conventions in your naming strategy.

Due to this, Jackson doesn't know that your getters (`getSurname()`, `getName()`) are referencing the fields `Surname` and `Name`. That's why it serializes both your fields and your getters separately to JSON.

To fix this, you can follow the Java naming conventions and use a lowercase letter for the first character of your fields.

For example:

```java
@Column(name = "name")
private String name; // Change this

@Column(name ="surname")
private String surname; // Change this
```

This will change your JSON output to:

```json
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "bryan",
  "surname": "Nicky"
}
```

If you want to keep your JSON with capital letters, you can use the `@JsonProperty` annotation:

```java
@JsonProperty("Name") // Add this
@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@JsonProperty("Surname") // Add this
@Column(name ="surname")
private String surname;
```

---

Unrelated to your question, but according to those naming conventions, your classes should start with a capital (eg. `Person`, `PersonController`, `PersonRepository`, ...).